# Where to find the official Cyanogenmod release notes?

Tags: cyanogenmod

Where are the official release notes for Cyanogenmod, in particular the 9.1 release? I wasn't able to find them.

Comment: This really isn't a good fit for this site. Certainly the official changelogs will have that information.

Comment: They're a bit hard to find though, at least if you assume they are called "release notes" :) I will rephrase my question to be more general.

Comment: http://www.cmxlog.com/11/ is a nice, neat site for checking out nightlies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check with the [official changelog site](http://changelog.bbqdroid.org/)? Or the [XDA thread on 9.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1858815)? The latter mentions http://cm-kang.appspot.com/anzu/ics for the changelog. And then there's [this page](http://cm9log.appspot.com/?device=galaxysmtd) where you even can filter changes by devices (probably the best source to check).

If you need more details: All that from page 1 of a simple Google search for [cyanogenmod changelog "9.1"](http://www.google.de/search?q=cyanogenmod+changelog+%229.1%22) (<- hint! ;) )

To the first (and explicit) question: If there were any new features? That probably very much depends on your device. So using the last changelog source I mentioned, filtering by the device you want to know this about, you will be able to answer your question. As I don't know your device, I can't ;)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: OP has rephrased his Question

A good start is also the [CyanogenMod blog](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog)

For CM9.1 it's:

A new NFC payment system, SimplyTapp has been added:

> **Let’s try something new: CM9.1 and SimplyTapp:**
>
> Welcome to Tapp!  A near field communication (NFC) payment platform for the CyanogenMod community and powered by SimplyTapp. Founded by two CM enthusiasts, Doug and Ted, Simplytapp provides a method for evolving, securing and expanding  NFC payments.

See CyanogenMod's [blog post](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod9-1-and-simplytapp) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

A condensed changelog containing only "notable new features" can be accessed from within Cyanogenmod via the settings menu -> about phone -> view changelog.